# Passing multiple parameters to a directive

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am trying to extend [this directive](https://audacitus.com/site/2017/02/28/converting-treehouses-asynchronous-image-loading-tutorial-into-an-ionic-2-directive/), called `img-preload`,  to accept a second parameter. Currently, it can be used like this:

```
<img img-preload="http://some_remote_image_url">
```

How can I pass a second parameter to it? I need something like this, were `img-preload-parameter2` is bound to a second input in `img-pareload` directive:

```
<img img-preload="http://some_remote_image_url" [img-preload-parameter2]='assets/image2.png'>
```

**Update**

My complete use case is as follows, where `errorImage` is the second parameter:

```
<img class='card-image' [class.red]='isRed(item)' 
            img-preloader="{{getImage(item)}}" 
            [errorImage]='assets/imgs/default.png'
            (error)='onError(item)'
            [class.error]='item.error' />
```

The directive code:

```
export class ImagePreloader implements OnInit {
@Input('img-preloader') targetSource: string;
@Input('errorImage') errorImage: string;
```

This gives me the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'png' of undefined
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (MyPage.html:59)
>       at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14339)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13508)
>       at callWithDebugContext (core.js:14740)
>       at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (core.js:14277)
>       at ViewRef_.detectChanges (core.js:11300)
>       at VirtualScroll._stepChangeDetection (virtual-scroll.js:559)
>       at virtual-scroll.js:497
>       at dispatch (dom-controller.js:139)
>       at DomController._flush (dom-controller.js:108)

Comment: Try `errorImage='assets/imgs/default.png'` or `[errorImage]="'assets/imgs/default.png'"`

Comment: Thanks, `errorImage='assets/imgs/default.png'` works! I appreciate if you could explain the difference.

Comment: When you use square brackets angular expects expression `assets/imgs/default.png` It tries to resolve `png` property on `default`. If you want to pass param as string you should either omit square brackets or use inner quotes like `[input]="'string in quotes'"`